# Svg Spray chart

Tags: html, css, svg

Actually I am new to SVG. I need's to draw baseball spray chart as have in below.Please help how to get this exactly and each section dynamically varies.Is it possible to draw using HTML CSS.Thanks.

[image]

#### UPDATE

I'm updating the question with the OP's comments that are important:

> I forget to tell you it is a baseball ground. Consider batter on PA and we are showing batter hit location in percentage around the ground in a game.

Comment: I understand that the data can vary. Can you add an example of how your data (an object - I suppose) looks like?

Comment: @enxaneta It seems array(3,3,29,13,11,18,23);

Comment: I suppose you decide the the color on base of the value. How do you decide the size of the pie element 3+3+29+13 = 48; 11+18+23= 52;

Comment: @enxaneta I forget to tell you it is a baseball ground.Consider batter on PA and we are showing batter hit location in percentage around the ground in a game.

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried, what you researched and what specific programming question you have about your current task. Do note [so] is not a free coding service, but a place where you can get answers or insight about ***your*** code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps:

1. you draw the individual paths
2. you draw the paths for the text (text on a path)
3. you draw the text

```js
let R = 200;// the outer radius
let r = 120;// the middle radius
let objects = [];// an array for the paths


class pathObj{
  constructor(a1,a2,R,r,path,text){
    this.a1 = a1; //starting angle
    this.a2 = a2; // ending angle
    this.R = R;//the outer radius
    this.r = r;// the middle radius
    this.rm = r + 2*(R - r)/3; // the radius for the text path
    this.path = document.querySelector(`#${path}`);
    this.textpath = document.querySelector(`#p${path}`);
    this.textElement = document.querySelector(`#t${path}`);
    this.textPath = document.querySelector(`#t${path} textPath`);
    this.textPath.textContent = text;
    
    // points to draw the paths
    this.p1 = {
     x:this.R*Math.cos(this.a1),
     y:this.R*Math.sin(this.a1)
    };
    this.p2 = {
     x:this.R*Math.cos(this.a2),
     y:this.R*Math.sin(this.a2)
    }
   this.p3 = {
     x:this.r*Math.cos(this.a2),
     y:this.r*Math.sin(this.a2)
    }
    this.p4 = {
     x:this.r*Math.cos(this.a1),
     y:this.r*Math.sin(this.a1)
    }
     this.p5 = {
     x:this.rm*Math.cos(this.a1),
     y:this.rm*Math.sin(this.a1)
    }
    this.p6 = {
     x:this.rm*Math.cos(this.a2),
     y:this.rm*Math.sin(this.a2)
    }
  }

  draw(){
    // the d attribute for the main path
    let d = `M${this.p1.x},${this.p1.y}
             A${this.R},${this.R} 0 0 1 ${this.p2.x},${this.p2.y}
             L${this.p3.x},${this.p3.y}
             A${this.r},${this.r} 0 0 0 ${this.p4.x},${this.p4.y}
             Z`;
    // the d attribute for the text path         
    let d1 = `M${this.p5.x},${this.p5.y}
             A${this.R},${this.R} 0 0 1 ${this.p6.x},${this.p6.y}`
    
    
    this.path.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
    this.textpath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d1);
    
  }
  
}

// create the objects and push into the objects array
objects.push(new pathObj(0,Math.PI/6,R,r,"a","11%"));
objects.push(new pathObj(Math.PI/6,Math.PI/3,R,r,"b","18%"));
objects.push(new pathObj(Math.PI/3,Math.PI/2,R,r,"c","23%"));
objects.push(new pathObj(0,Math.PI/8,r,0,"d","3%"));
objects.push(new pathObj(Math.PI/8,Math.PI/4,r,0,"e","3%"));
objects.push(new pathObj(Math.PI/4,3*Math.PI/8,r,0,"f","29%"));
objects.push(new pathObj(3*Math.PI/8,Math.PI/2,r,0,"g","13%"));
objects.forEach(o=>o.draw())
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid }
path{stroke:black; fill:transparent;}
text{ text-anchor:middle;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-200 -250 400 250">
<defs>
   <path id="pa" /> 
   <path id="pb" />
   <path id="pc" />
   <path id="pd" />
   <path id="pe" />
   <path id="pf" />
   <path id="pg" />
  </defs> 
<g transform="rotate(-135)">
  <path id="a" /><text id="ta"><textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#pa"></textPath></text>
  <path id="b" /><text id="tb"><textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#pb"></textPath></text>
  <path id="c" /><text id="tc"><textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#pc"></textPath></text>
  <path id="d" /><text id="td"><textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#pd"></textPath></text>
  <path id="e" /><text id="te"><textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#pe"></textPath></text>
  <path id="f" /><text id="tf"><textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#pf"></textPath></text>
  <path id="g" /><text id="tg"><textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#pg"></textPath></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me accept this for spending your wonderful time for me.One more thing is it possible to design using path instead of javascript?